# Get value on page load asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string guest= Session["consumer"].ToString() ; 

            }
          }


protected void user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      user.text = guest;
    }
```

how to get value from guest on page load to user.text . - (sr my english is bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. First, just check the same `Session` value again:

```
protected void user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  user.text = Session["consumer"].ToString();
}
```

Second, use a class member:

```
private string guest;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    guest = Session["consumer"].ToString(); 
}

protected void user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     user.text = guest;
}
```

Just be *very careful* here to only use this during the same life cycle. The `guest` member value will not survive a postback.

Another option is to use a property.

```
private string guest {get; set;}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    guest = Session["consumer"].ToString(); 
}

protected void user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     user.text = guest;
}
```

It seems pretty much the same as the previous option, but I like it because you can change the property to interact directly with the Session or ViewState if you want:

```
private string guest 
{
    get {return Session["consumer"].ToString();}
    set {Session["consume"] = value;}
}

protected void user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     user.text = guest;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I wonder if abstracting the property into to base class or static instance would have been examples worth sharing also.